# Extract images with transparency from a PDF Document

Tags: pdf, images

I have a PDF Document with similar images as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155687/transparent-images-in-pdf question.
I want to extract them using `pdfimages` from the poppler project.
Viewing the PDF document, the images are displayed correctly, with parts of them transparent (as they should), but the extracted image files have white pixels for the original transparent parts. And `pdfimages` produces no 'mask' images as it does for others

1. How do i extract the images correctly retaining the transparency as displayed in the pdf.
2. How is it described in the pdf, which parts of the image should be transparent when there is no mask?

Comment: "produces no 'mask' images as it does for others" are you referring to the mask image (not) being emitted sequentially as a separate image? It is possible that transparency was flattened when emitting the pdf, this sometimes resolves export/rendering issues, so it may be done selectively. It may also be an older PDF revision document which also tended to flatten transparency.

Comment: Yes, for the images in question there is only one file, the real picture on a white background.
The PDF File is Version 1.7.